Android Studio keeps indexing excluded C++ folders after adding Git-based versioning to build.gradle.kts
I'm working on an Android project with a mix of Java, Kotlin, and C++ code. The project includes large C++ libraries in the binary/jni directory, which I have excluded from indexing by click Mark Directory as > Excluded
My .iml file looks like this:
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../binary/jni/boost" />
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../binary/jni/miniupnp" />
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../../binary/jni/openssl" />

Despite these exclusions, Android Studio starts indexing these folders if I make changes to my build.gradle.kts, especially after adding logic to dynamically update the app version using Git.
Here's an example of my current build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.compose)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.project"
    compileSdk = 34
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        compose = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.project"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionName = file("${rootProject.projectDir}/version.txt").readText().trim()
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters += listOf("arm64-v8a", "x86_64")
        }
    }
}

The version.txt file is generated using a Git command git describe --tags --always, and it contains a string like v1.0.0-abc123. The Gradle script reads this file to set versionName.
Also it happens if i just set and sync Gradle
versionName = "v1.0.0-abc123"

The issue seems to be that modifying build.gradle.kts triggers a project sync, which somehow ignores the excluded folders in the .iml configuration. This leads to unnecessary indexing of large libs (e.g., Boost libraries), making the IDE almost unusable during the process.
I use Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1 Patch 2 Linux.
What I’ve Tried

Excluding the folders in .iml (as shown above).

Using the IDEA Gradle plugin with excludeDirs:


    idea {
        module {
            excludeDirs += file("binary/jni/boost")
            excludeDirs += file("binary/jni/miniupnp")
            excludeDirs += file("binary/jni/openssl")
        }
    }


Setting .iml files to read-only by changing file permissions for .idea/modules/app/\*.iml. However, this also did not resolve the issue. It creates new .idea/modules/app/\*.iml~ and index all excluded folders

No one solution helped me. After syncing gradle,  ide ignores excluded folders. It looks like a bug of IDE.
What I Need Help With:

Why is Android Studio ignoring the exclusions defined in the .iml file after modifying build.gradle.kts?

How can I prevent indexing of excluded folders even if I edit build.gradle.kts?


